# React: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I´m trying to make a React calculator. I´m building my components for an initial test, and I can´t seem to get it to compile. I think i´m not passing state as props properly to the Display component, but I don´t really know what I´m doing wrong.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "[]" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <Button value={"1"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"2"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"3"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"4"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"5"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"6"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"7"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"8"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"9"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"."} type="input" />
        <Button value={"="} type="input" />
        <Button value={"Clear"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"add"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"substract"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"multiply"} type="input" />
        <Button value={"divide"} type="input" />
        <Display value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Button = props => {
  return <input type="Button" value={props.value} />;
};

const Display = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.state.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` prop given to your `Display` component will be called `value`, not `state.value`:

```js
const Display = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you don´t mind my asking, why isn´t it props.state.value? since it´s the "value" property inside state

Comment: @HernanAriel Only the name of the props given to your components matter. It doesn't matter if you write `<Display value={this.state.some.very.deep.value} />` or  `<Display value="foo" />`. The prop will always be reached by the prop name.